# drupal 7 newly created custom module does not showing up in module list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i am new to drupal, currently learning drupal 7.

i am referring book for drupal 7

i was trying to create my first custom module

in the book it was mention that you can create module in one of the following directory

1) /sites/all/modules

2) /sites/default/modules

name of my module is **first**

i have created my module in /sites/default/modules/first

in this directories there are two file

1)**first.info**

2)**first.module**

content of first .info files are

```
;$Id$
name = First
description = A first module.
package = Drupal 7 Development
core = 7.x
files[] = first.module
;dependencies[] = autoload
;php = 5.4
```

content of fisrt.module files are

```
<?php
// $Id$
/**
* @file
* A module exemplifying Drupal coding practices and APIs.
*
* This module provides a block that lists all of the
* installed modules. It illustrates coding standards,
* practices, and API use for Drupal 7.
*/
/**
* Implements hook_help().
*/

function first_help($path, $arg) {
if ($path == 'admin/help#first') {
return t('A demonstration module.');
}
}
?>
```

when i try to check list of modules i am not able to see module that i created

i have tired clearing cache and check still not showing

can anybody tell me where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

**Module Location**
Most people choose to put modules in the `/sites/all/modules` or `/sites/domain.com/modules` folders (not `sites/default...`). For most common Drupal installations you should place it in `sites/all/modules`.

**Info File**
Only Name, Description and Core are required in your info file. Start by removing everything except those values.

```
name = First
description = A first module.
core = 7.x
```

See [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](http://drupal.org/node/542202) for more information.

Some notes:

- The "package" Property "should only be used by large multi-module packages"
- You don't need to declare your module's `.module` file in the "files" Property.
- Remove the commented out lines for now. If your module really requires PHP 5.4, you can add that back in later after you're done troubleshooting.

Comment: Check the file names on your info and module files. You have typos in both above (info file name has a space and module file name is misspelled).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problems by starting my .info file with

```
name = First
```

and make my file encode:

> UTF-8 without BOM

you can find it easy when using Notpade++

Answer (score 0):

```
function test_example_help($path, $arg){
switch ($path) {
case "admin/help#test_example":
return '<p>' . t("test module to see how it works and shows") . '</p>';
break;
}
```

try the following example using a switch statement to see whether it works

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the **?>** that marks the end of the php code.This is done to prevent white space to breakup HTTP headers.